# phonegap 3.0 console.log plugin http:localhost/!gap_exec 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, console.log

I've installed the console.log plugin "$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console" to my phonegap 3.0 project.

When I do console.log("xxx") in xcode, it work fine without any problem / error.

However when I test it in a web browser. The error "http:localhost/!gap_exec 404 NOT FOUND" appeared in the web browser console. When I comment out the console.log("xxx"), this error is disappear.

I just wonder whether it is really work fine in xcode. coz sometime xcode won't display javascript error.

Is there any debug tools for develop phonegap apps for ios / android?

Answer (score 0):

Any cordova(phonegap) plugins is not for the web browser. when we install the console plugins it works on actual device because deviceready event fires but in case of web browser deviceready does not fire thus plugins are not working so, if you are doing so then please remove cordova.js file from your html and try in web-browser. but when you are ready with device include that file it is mandatory.

`http:localhost/!gap_exec 404 NOT FOUND` errors simply means that cordova(phonegap) does not find the actual device environment.